# If statement comparing two NSStrings not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement, nsstring

Am having problems with what looks like a very simple IF statement, here is the code:

```
NSString * lowerCaseSubject = [_subjectParameter lowercaseString];
    NSString * subjectPriceString = nil;

if (_subjectParameter) {
        for (int p=0; p < arr.count; p++) {
            subjectPriceString = [arr[p] valueForKeyPath: @"name"];
            if (subjectPriceString == lowerCaseSubject) {
                float price = [[arr[p] valueForKeyPath: @"pricePerHour"]floatValue];
                priceLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", price];
            }
        }

    }else{
```

I'm debugging and find that the IF statement below is never set true and so the  statements following it never executed:

```
if (subjectPriceString == lowerCaseSubject) {
```

This, despite the following field value showing:

[image]

Have been trying to fix for ages and getting no where, can anyone see what I am missing here?
Thanks

Comment: for string comparisons with NSString use isEqualToString: method not ==

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if ([subjectPriceString isEqualToString:lowerCaseSubject]){
     // do stuff
}
```